# When are we getting the exact message "timeout" in Retrofit onFailure()?

Tags: retrofit2

I got a `SocketTimeoutException`. In the `onFailure` method, when I call `t.getMessage()`, it returns exactly `"timeout"`

Here is my code:

```
private void getCouponsService() {

    APIInterface mObjInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);

    Call<CouponsResponseModel> call = mObjInterface.getCoupons();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<CouponsResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CouponsResponseModel> call, Response<CouponsResponseModel> response) {

            if (response.code() == 200) {

                // Handle success response
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CouponsResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {

            String message = t.getMessage();

        }
    });
}
```

The value of `message` is exactly `"timeout"`. In which scenario are we supposed to get that message? I expected the output to be `Unable to resolve host "abc.domainname.in": No address associated with hostname`.